# .htaccess: Rewrite to subdirectory with a twist

Tags: .htaccess

I have `domain-a.com` and `domain-b.com`. The host runs a multi-site Contao installation with two sites to which both domains are assigned respectively. Both sites are supposed to have a Wordpress blog in a `/blog` subfolder. Of course they realistically can not, so the first one is `domain-a.com/blog` and the second is `domain-b.com/blog-b`.

Wrapping my head around .htaccess has proven to be really difficult for me and I just can't figure out how to get this logic to work:

```
if 
  domain is domain-b 
and 
  request_uri starts with /blog 
rewrite to domain-b/blog-b/$1
```

I tried like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-b\.comt [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /blog-b/$1
```

Does not work. How is it done?

Comment: `.comt` is just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think the `$1` is capturing the /blog/ in the incoming url, so it's doing `/blog-b/blog/...`

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-b\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ /blog-b/$1 [NC,L]
```

Also, depending if you have a RewriteBase, the leading slash in the RewriteRule may need to be removed.